# How to reduce the spacing between boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot

does anyone know how I can reduce the spacing between two boxplots in a graphic such as the attached, while also reducing the width of the graph (in other words, make the graph more compact)? I can reduce their spacing using the parameter `at = c(0, 0.5)` but this just shifts the whitespace to either side, rather than reducing the width of the graph as I was hoping for. I am using the boxplot function in R to create my boxplots.
[image: My boxplot]

Comment: What happens when you simply make your plotting window narrower?

Comment: I had tried that before and it didn't really work but with a combination of making the plotting window narrower, using the at parameter and reducing the text size of my labels I have managed to get an acceptable graph

Answer (score 1):

You could use `at` to change the positions of your box plots. First I created some reproducible data. Here you can see the difference between a standard `at` and one which is adjusted. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
boxplot(samples~tree_type, data = df)
```

[image]

```r
boxplot(samples~tree_type, data = df, 
        at = c(0, 0.85))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

**Data**

```
set.seed(7) # for reproducibility 
df <- data.frame(tree_type = rep(c("Confirous", "Broad-leaved"), each = 20),
                 samples = runif(40))
```